# sigprocmask doesn't restore my signal handler

Tags: c, sockets, unix, signals, sigprocmask

I have a problem with my code C Unix. I'll copy crucial parts:
So after the first sigprocmask I send a signal, after the SIG_UNBLOCK, doesn't work the previous handle(gestisciSignalDopoReg) instead the standard handle manage my signal, so it simply terminate the process... What's wrong? Thanks

```
struct sigaction gestoreSegnale;
sigset_t mask;
sigemptyset(&mask);
sigaddset(&mask,SIGTERM);
sigaddset(&mask,SIGINT);
sigaddset(&mask,SIGALRM);
sigaddset(&mask,SIGQUIT);
sigaddset(&mask,SIGHUP);
sigaddset(&mask,SIGSEGV);
sigaddset(&mask,SIGILL);
sigaddset(&mask,SIGPIPE);
void setSegnali(int segn,__sighandler_t handler){
  gestoreSegnale.sa_handler=handler;
  gestoreSegnale.sa_mask=mask;

  sigaction(segn, &gestoreSegnale, NULL);
}
void eseguiSetSegnali(__sighandler_t handler){
  setSegnali(SIGQUIT, handler);
  setSegnali(SIGSEGV, handler);
  setSegnali(SIGILL, handler);
  setSegnali(SIGHUP, handler);
  setSegnali(SIGTERM, handler);
  setSegnali(SIGINT, handler);
}
void main(){
 eseguiSetSegnali(gestisciSIGNALDopoReg);
 sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,&mask,NULL);
 .........other part of code......... 
 sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK,&mask,NULL);
}
```

please! I need help!

Answer (score 4):

You do not initialize the `sa_flags` field of your `struct sigaction`, so it may contain garbage values. It is possible that the `SA_RESETHAND` bit is set, which according to the man page will give you this behavior:

> ```
>        SA_RESETHAND
>               Restore the signal action to the default state once the signal handler has been called.  This flag  is
>               only  meaningful  when establishing a signal handler.  SA_ONESHOT is an obsolete, non-standard synonym
>               for this flag.
> ```

If your signal handler has run once, that would cause it to be cleared and return to the default, so you may just need to zero out the flags like:

```
void setSegnali(int segn,__sighandler_t handler){
  gestoreSegnale.sa_handler=handler;
  gestoreSegnale.sa_mask=mask;
  /* Make sure to clear flags */
  gestoreSegnale.sa_flags=0;

  sigaction(segn, &gestoreSegnale, NULL);
}
```

At any rate, the following little example works:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void handler(int sig) {
    printf("HUP %d\n", sig);
}

void main(){
    struct sigaction act;

    /* Block SIGHUP while the signal handler is running */
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    sigaddset(&act.sa_mask,SIGHUP);

    /* Define handler for signal */
    act.sa_handler = handler;

    /* Clear flags */
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    act.sa_restorer = NULL;

    /* Install handler for SIGHUP */
    sigaction(SIGHUP, &act, NULL);

    /* Set mask to block SIGHUP */
    sigset_t mask;
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGHUP);

    /* Block SIGHUP */
    printf("Blocking SIGHUP\n");
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,&mask,NULL);
    printf("Sleeping\n");
    sleep(60);
    /* Unblock SIGHUP */
    printf("Unblocking SIGHUP\n");
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK,&mask,NULL);
    printf("Sleeping again\n");
    while(1)
        sleep(60);
}
```

If run, you see the desired result:

```
$ ./sigtest 
Blocking SIGHUP
Sleeping             <-- SIGHUP sent from another terminal here but blocked
Unblocking SIGHUP
HUP 1                <-- Signal sent earlier now delivered and handled
Sleeping again
HUP 1                <-- Further signals sent are all handled
HUP 1
HUP 1
^C
```